# YamlDotnet does set references correct

Tags: .net, serialization, yaml, yamldotnet

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I serialize it:

```
        var parentId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = parentId, Parent = Guid.Empty, Name = "Parent"},
            new Item {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Parent = parentId, Name = "Child"}
        };

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, items);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

The output is:

```
- Id: 1c49bc54-d0e3-494e-8fd7-b9ffd8c1892a
  Name: Parent
- Id: dd54864a-61f7-4d73-b89d-9bd4e4c2c8f4
  Parent: *o0
  Name: Child
```

There is a reference `*o0` created which is the ID of the other class which is it's parent. But YamlDotnet does not define this reference, therefore when deserializing I get an error  saying it's missing an anchor.

Is this a bug in the framework or is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: The example given in the YamlDotnet properly creates an anchor for a referenced mapping. But you have to write the serializer/emitter in such a way that any object can be an anchor and it looks like YamlDotnet doesn't support that (which is a bug).

Comment: I thought so, I already created an issue on the github page as well https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/198 . I think we can work around this problem.

Comment: I had seen your bugreport. The anchor/alias implementation looks non-standard. It also supports [aliases before anchors](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet.Test/Serialization/SerializationTests.cs#L213) where the YAML 1.2 standard explicitly states the first node use should have the anchor (thus disallowing forward referencing).